# Configure file naming & presents in Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: premiere, encoding

I'm running the latest version of Premiere Pro & Encoder (CS6). Encoder has a watch folder capability to automatically encode files, but it defaults to Flash output with a specific preset & gives the file the name of the original sequence selected in the Premiere project.

What I'd like to do is drop a Premiere project file in a watch folder and have my rendering server pickup the file and start encoding it but I want to configure a specific output file type, present & name the output file the name of the Premiere project file. I can't figure how to do this or if it is even possible (aside from the watch folder & encoding).

The current project I'm on has over 100 video outputs and we're looking at 1 Premiere project per output. This is just the first project... looking at many more in the future so working on a workflow now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format, once you add a watch folder to your watch folders window, click the F4V under the format tab, and you can configure how you want each video from that watch folder to be set as...

Furthermore if you click the output folder destination, you can change the filename and destination in which the movie will be saved to.

Hope this helps